# Role created by environment variable set by kubernetes secret in side official postgres image ends with a `+`

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes

I am seeing a very strange issue trying to start the official `postgres:14.6-alpine` image on Kubernetes.

For reference the official postgres image allows for configuring the initialization script using the `POSTGRES_USER`, `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`, and `POSTGRES_DB` environment variables.

I have the following secret and configmap defined:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: postgres-credentials
data:
  DATABASE_URL: cG9zdGdyZXM6Ly9sZXRzY2h1cmNoOnBhc3N3b3JkQHBvc3RncmVzOjU0MzIvbGV0c2NodXJjaA==
  POSTGRES_USER: bGV0c2NodXJjaA==
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: cGFzc3dvcmQ=
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: postgres-config
data:
  POSTGRES_DB: letschurch
```

The value `POSTGRES_USER` value of `bGV0c2NodXJjaA==` decodes to `letschurch` and the `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` value of `cGFzc3dvcmQ=` decodes to `password`.

I also have the following deployment:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
        - image: postgres:14.6-alpine
          name: postgres
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: postgres-config
            - secretRef:
                name: postgres-credentials
```

When I shell into the running container, I can echo out the environment variables, and they appear to be intact:

```
postgres-74f67b778-lsv4c:/# echo $POSTGRES_USER
letschurch
postgres-74f67b778-lsv4c:/# echo $POSTGRES_PASSWORD
password
postgres-74f67b778-lsv4c:/# echo $POSTGRES_DB
letschurch
postgres-74f67b778-lsv4c:/# echo -n $POSTGRES_USER | wc -c
10
postgres-74f67b778-lsv4c:/# echo -n $POSTGRES_PASSWORD | wc -c
8
postgres-74f67b778-lsv4c:/# echo -n $POSTGRES_DB | wc -c
10
postgres-74f67b778-lsv4c:/# [ "$POSTGRES_USER" = "$POSTGRES_DB" ] && echo 'good!'
good!
```

However, I am not able to connect with the role `letschurch`. I can connect as `temporal` (another role I have set up with an init script), and when I run `\l` and `\du` I see that the role (but not the database name) have a `+` appended:

```
temporal=> \l
                                        List of databases
        Name         |   Owner    | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |    Access privileges     
---------------------+------------+----------+------------+------------+--------------------------
 letschurch          | letschurch+| UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 

temporal=> \du
                                    List of roles
 Role name  |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 letschurch+| Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
            |                                                            | 
 temporal   |                                                            | {}
```

At first I thought that the base64-encoded `POSTGRES_USER` environment variable might have some whitespace or something encoded in it, so I double checked that I was encoding the value properly with `echo -n letschurch | base64`, and as you can see in the shell output above the resulting value is exactly 10 characters long, no extra whitespace. Also, the `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_DB` environment variables are equal, but they appear to result in different outcomes in postgres.

Also, this does not happen with `docker-compose`. Given the following configuration, everything works as expected:

```yaml
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.6-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: letschurch
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: letschurch
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
```

What am I missing here? Why does the `letschurch` role get a `+` appended to it? Is there something to do with `secret`s that doesn't apply to `configMap`s that I'm missing?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior: if I deploy your manifests into a local k8s cluster, I can authenticate as `letschurch` using password `password`. Here [a demo](https://asciinema.org/a/ha9Ap81VocXzHb8ZLVhO4who5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this had to do with a specific setting I had enabled for Docker Desktop for Mac:

[image: Docker Desktop Settings]

I had changed from the default value (`gRPC FUSE`) to `VirtioFS`. When I changed it back to `gRPC FUSE` a number of issues resolved themselves, this one included.